# Why was this "not an answer" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

To my surprise I saw this in my flagging history:

> [My computer boots up with Ubuntu: How can I tell what's on my hard
>   disk?](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/312728/1) -  answered 1 hour ago by TomC
>
> not an answer – 46 mins ago  ***declined*** - flags should only be used to
>   make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

---

The answer it is concerning is not an answer at all, by three parts:

> Welcome to the world of Linux. In command mode, you can type uname -a
>   This will show you the version of Linux, the architecture (probably
>   i386) and build date, along with some more information. But the menu
>   already indicated that it is version 3.0, which is really ancient, and
>   no longer supported.

As I commented also, this part is about the Linux command line (terminal/Bash) while the question is about the Grub command line. I guess the user misinterpreted the question.

> It is quite possible that this laptop has no wireless and maybe not a
>   wired internet connection, which limits the usefulness in today's
>   computer world.

This has nothing to do with the question.

> You could possible use it as a doorstop (ha! ha!). In reality, unless
>   you want to use it as a Linux learning tool, you might be better off
>   selling it on Ebay as a collector's item. Sorry, but that's my
>   opinion.

I don't understand what this is about, and it's his *opinion* anyway.

**So, to improve my flagging skills, why is the "not an answer" flag declined here?**

---

By the way, right after my flag was declined the post re-appeared in the 10k tool queue:

[image]

Comment: Seeing the userbox for TomC in the post made me think this was his meta-post and has been confusing my socks off. Go home moderator, you're drunk!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comment when flagging a post as "not an answer" says:

> ... but it does not attempt to answer the question.

So in my eyes the flag should not be used as long as the poster tries to give an answer.

Comment: I agree with guntbert.  The only time I would use Not an Answer on an attempted answer is if it answers, say, the *wrong* question and therefore doesn't give an answer to what is being asked.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't handle this flag but I did handle one very much like it yesterday.

On a technical level, the answer you flagged is an answer, it's just not a very good one. `uname -a` will give you a fair indication about what you're currently running. Now that by no means explains what's on the entire harddisk and even with a uname string, you're left with some detective work. Yeah it's crappy, but it is a partial.

When you hit something like this your reaction should be:

- Edit the post if it's easily fixable.
- Leave a comment - explain what's wrong so the writer has a chance to fix or delete it.
- Vote down if it's technically incorrect to let the OP and others know it's bad. That's the whole point of there being a down-vote button.
- After all of that, call for a moderator if it's dangerously incorrect or wildly offtopic, etc.

The tools that exist here are supposed to further users' abilities to deal with light moderation issues without requiring one of a very limited number of moderators.

In this case the question simply didn't need our eyes. A comment and -1 was all that was required.

Comment: I'm very surprised by this answer, actually. "`uname -a` will give you a fair indication [...]" Well, no, not in the context of the question as I tried to point out. Would an answer "run `format C:`" to a question how to format a partition in Ubuntu also be an answer then? In my opinion this answer sounds like we don't even need the "not an answer" flag at all.

Comment: There are plenty of cases where Not An Answer gets used: people asking follow up questions or posting me-toos and thanks. What I'm saying here is use the voting and commenting systems to deal with bad answers.

Comment: I concur with what has been said. Use voting and comments to fix bad answers.

Comment: I really still disagree with your qualification of the post being an answer. My definition of a "bad answer" is completely different I guess.

Comment: @gertvdijk, read the comment, when flagging: "... it does not attempt to answer the question...". So as long as someone tries to give an answer the flag should not be used.

Comment: @guntbert Good point. Add that as an answer, I'd say.