# Don't be shy and vote ;)

Tags: discussion, voting

I know is pretty difficult finding good/interesting questions/answers, but the amount of votes per week/month/quarter leave so much to hope for. I feel alone in the first place on the [quarter rankings](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter) and we need to be more cohesive in how we use the tools we are given if we expect quality in the questions/answer. Also remember that voting up and voting down bad questions doesn't cost anything (well only a click) and answers is only 1 reputation on bad answers.

[Thy are related to my recent rant about flagging bad/wrong answers as NAA.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7696/169736)

Comment: Downvotes cost 1 rep.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος you prefer leaving a wrong/misleading answer instead of downvoting it? That doesn't looks right.

Comment: 3 years ago, you said that "answers is only 1 reputation". I assume it doesn't hurt here, but, sometimes, I reserve my downvotes because I just got a milestone privilege, and don't want to lose it right away, or just keeping my rep. Note that downvoting answers on any meta (except Meta.SE) does cost you 0 rep, not 1.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I really don't know where you are coming from... I lost editing privileges on so at least 2 times that I remember, because I downvoted bad answers. I still downvote them, but losing reputation wasn't at any time a cause of concern.